# How to unbind Shift-Alt Up shortkey in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, shortcut-keys

How to unbind <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd> shortkey in Ubuntu 12.04? I can't find it in system's Keyboard shortcuts settings. I want to unbind this shortcut so I can use it in an application.

Answer (score 7):

It should be in > System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts (but I can't seem to find it there)

### Solution

Install **Compiz Config Settings**. To install if I remember it's

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Once installed:

- Go to -> Compiz Settings > Scale > Bindings > Initiate Window Picker
- Mouse Click > `<Shift><Alt><Up>` (a popup opens) > uncheck "Enabled"
- Done

Bug Report: [Scale: keyboard binding for "Initiate Window Picker For window Group" is non-functional](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/917380)

### Resources

[Alt-Shift-Up in the NetBeans Java Editor on Ubuntu](https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/alt_shift_up_in_the)

Comment: Very useful for shortcut in some editor like netbeans...thank you....